# Highcharts - show decimal places only if needed

Tags: highcharts

How do i make highchart's y label show decimal values **only if needed**?

Right now I am using

`yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null,
        },
        tickAmount: 5,
        labels: {
            format: "{value:.2f}",    // this stands for showing two decimal places
        },
    };`

The effect of this configuration, is that I see decimal places, even when they are not needed to represent number:

[image]

I want to see decimal places only if needed, for example:
3,14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **[formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter)** instead of format.

```
labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        }
```

**Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/625xcheb/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a modulo operation inside `yAxis.labels.formatter` to check if number has decimals and if so, use `Highcharts.numberFormat` function to display this number with two decimals. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Highcharts.numberFormat

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/y5s7vsvm/